# NodeJS Patreon API account link

Tags: node.js, api, post, oauth, patreon

I'm trying to connect user accounts on my website to patreon. I keep getting an access_denied error message in response to step 3. I'm following this [documentation](https://www.patreon.com/platform/documentation/oauth).

My node server code looks like this:

```
  socket.on("patreon_register",function(code,user){
        var reqString = "api.patreon.com/oauth2/token?code="
                        +code
                        +"&grant_type=authorization_code&client_id="
                        +settings.patreon.Client_ID
                        +"&client_secret="
                        +settings.patreon.Client_Secret
                        +"&redirect_uri="
                        +"http%3A%2F%2Fwww.levisinger.com%2F%3Fpage%3Dpatreon_success",                        
        req = querystring.stringify({
            "code": code,
            "grant_type": "authorization_code",
            "client_id": settings.patreon.Client_ID,
            "client_secret": settings.patreon.Client_Secret,
            "redirect_uri": "http%3A%2F%2Fwww.levisinger.com%2F%3Fpage%3Dpatreon_success"
            }),
        post_options = {
                host: 'api.patreon.com',
                port: '80',
                path: '/oauth2/token',
                method: 'POST',
                headers: {
                    'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
                    'Content-Length': Buffer.byteLength(req)
                }
            };        
        // Set up the request
        console.log(req);
        var post_req = http.request(post_options, function(res) {
            res.setEncoding('utf8');
            res.on('data', function (chunk) {
                console.log(chunk);
                if(
                    chunk.access_token &&
                    chunk.refresh_token &&
                    chunk.expires_in &&
                    chunk.scope &&
                    chunk.token_type
                ){
                    Auth.linkPatreon(user,chunk,function(err,res){
                        if(err){ socket.emit('patreon_register',false,res); }
                        else { socket.emit('patreon_register',true,res); }
                    });
                }
            });
        });
        // post the data
        post_req.write(req);
        post_req.end();
    });
```

The req variable that's actually sent to the server looks like this (changed my codes to generic values of course)

```
code=MY_RESPONSE_CODE&grant_type=authorization_code&client_id=MY_CLIENT_ID&client_secret=MY_CLIENT_SECRET&redirect_uri=MY_RESPONSE_URI
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Never mind... I re-did all of the steps I had done before, re-copied the keys and it's working now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end, my server looks like this and is working:

```
socket.on("patreon_register",function(code,user){
    var req = querystring.stringify({
            code: code,
            grant_type: "authorization_code",
            client_id: settings.patreon.Client_ID,
            client_secret: settings.patreon.Client_Secret,
            redirect_uri: settings.patreon.redirect_uri
        }),
    post_options = {
            host: 'api.patreon.com',
            port: '80',
            path: '/oauth2/token',
            method: 'POST',
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
                'Content-Length': Buffer.byteLength(req)
            }
        };        
    // Set up the request
    console.log(req);
    var post_req = http.request(post_options, function(res) {
        res.setEncoding('utf8');
        res.on('data', function (chunk) {
            chunk = JSON.parse(chunk);
            console.log(chunk);
            if(!chunk["error"]){
                console.log("Linking!");
                Auth.linkPatreon(user,chunk,function(err,res){
                    if(err){ socket.emit('patreon_register',false,res); }
                    else { socket.emit('patreon_register',true,res); }
                    console.log("Linked!");
                });
            }
        });
    });
```